# Parallel HTTP requests library for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to make number of http requests in parallel; with either one error response or a number of them. Having done that myself a few times (with just a loop & counter), I'd like to use one that is more robust, and will handle edge cases.

Do you know if there's a library / micro-framework out there that will do this? One, to which I can provide a number of URLs, a success callback method (for each), a single error callback; and possibly other options. This library would follow 301s, call the err-cb if any or all requests time-out or fail.

Comment: Isn't asynchronous (aka AJAX) parallel already?

Comment: @Diodeus it absolutely is (unless configured to be sync, of course); and because it is, handling 10/20 of these requests, their individual errors and time-outs is tedious and error-prone. That's why I'm asking whether there's a library or utility that already does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the flow-control libraries:

- [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step)
- [Seq](https://github.com/substack/node-seq)
- [Futures](http://coolaj86.info/futures/)
- [TameJS](http://tamejs.org/)
- [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: "Step". I selected the simplest one that did the job. By simplest I mean: fewest loc to implement the requirements above, and the smallest set of features in the lib itself. "Step" won.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js does have [maxSockets](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#agent.maxSockets). I think this library might come close to your requirements =>
https://github.com/SaltwaterC/http-get?

Comment: http-get looks interesting. I didn't find a way to have a single err for 'n' number of requests in it though. Also, I wish maxSockets wasn't global; but that's a different topic.

Comment: @Yuriy or maybe request => https://github.com/mikeal/request,which also is very popular.. I think coding these requirements should not be to hard to accomplish... But I also think you should search search.npmjs.org and http://github.com/ry/node/wiki/modules. That are just two modules. request is the most popular one and the other in my question has recently had a commit...